# Dialogflow: How are user-contexts differentiated

Tags: dialogflow-es

How does Dialogflow differentiate between different customers 
I am storing user related data in contexts, how does dialogflow differentiate between different users using dialogflow simultaneously and keep contexts specific to users

Use case is that many users will make a request to a vendor and the vendor would make a request to dialogflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dialogflow keeps track of context based on the session ID, so even if two users are in the same context, you will be able to see a difference in their session. Below is a sample from the Dialogflow simulator. You can find it under the Diagnostic Info button.

```
"outputContexts": [
  {
    "name": "projects/[ProjectName]/agent/sessions/[SessionID]/contexts/[ContextName]",
    "lifespanCount": 5,
    }
  }
],
```

Comment: Hey Jordi
How can I differentiate through my webhook between users. This is what I have right now: (I am using express) 
```
var session = require('express-session')
const SESSION_ID = uuid.v4();
app.use(session({ secret: SESSION_ID, cookie: { secure:false}}));
```

Comment: I use this SESSION_ID as defined above with response to dialogflow (basically as [SessionID] in your above answer

Comment: I think the session Id should be provided through whatever sdk you are using for Dialogflow, but that is probably easier to do through a new question, than in the comments. So if you need help with another question, please make another one

Comment: And if your current question is now answered please mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Absolutely! Thank you Jordi